# Nonin Onyx II 9560 data

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am creating an android app to ready in the pulse oximeter data using the bluetooth interface. I am able to connect and I see the data coming in but it does not match any of the formats (13 or 2, 7,8) defined in the OEM spec.

Here is the data dump of what I am getting. Does anyone have any idea what this could be ?

thanks!

```
Hex Dump of data Read [54] 
 e2 00 00 32 80 00 00 00 00 01 00 2a 50 79 00 26    "...2.......*Py.&"
 80 00 00 00 80 00 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80    "................"
 00 00 00 08 00 1c 05 01 00 00 94 97 01 91 00 01    "................"
 01 00 00 00 00 00 

                             "......"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learnt from the Nonin developer that this is just the initial message that is received from the device. The android device has to respond and receive a set of transactions before the final measurement data is received.

I was using the HDP profile. When you use HDP, the you will have to follow the IEEE 11073 spec. If you want serial data you will have to use the SPP (Serial Port Profile).